# Can a deleted PGP secret key be recovered from private-keys-v1.d directory?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

Executing `gpg -K --with-keygrip` returns one key entry. However the private-keys-v1.d directory has two entries. I assume that one of them belongs to a secret key that has been deleted/removed.

Is there any way of restoring a secret key from this directory?

Answer (score 1):

The question is based on the wrong assumption that for each PGP pair there is one and only one entry in the private-keys-v1.d directory. The private-keys-v1.d directory comprises the [key store of the gpg-agent](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html) so apart from the private keys used by gpg there may exist [other keys used by SSH or X.509 or secret subkeys](https://lists.gt.net/gnupg/users/75276).

Deleted keys are not going to be present in this directory. On the other hand if you have at hand the private-keys-v1.d directory it is possible to restore the keys as explained [here](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2016-December/057246.html).